# No matter what I do I get permission denied

Tags: ruby

Hi I am running some code that scrapes a web page and then spits out a csv file here is that code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.drugs.com/pharmaceutical-companies.html"))
puts page.class #=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document


pharma_links = page.css("div.col-list-az a")

link= pharma_links.each{|link| puts link['href'] }
company = pharma_links.each{|link| puts link.text} 

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
   csv << [company, link]
end
```

The code works perfectly all the way till the end, where I get this error

```
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1282:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - file.csv (Errno::EACCES)
```

I have literally given myself ownership of the entire C: drive and still receive this error. Please help I am beyond my wits.  Also, I am new to Ruby so please be explicit in your answers.

I am running Windows 10 with 32-bit Ruby.

Comment: But what if it's not on C: drive? Print the value of `Dir.getwd` before that `CSV.open`. Do you have write access to _that_?

Comment: Also this line is not doing what you think it does: `link= pharma_links.each{|link| puts link['href'] }`. You'll find out when you fix that permission error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What is that line doing? in my console its creating a list of the href links, which is what I want.  And according to the error message `C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/csv.rb:1282:in initialize: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - file.csv (Errno::EACCES)` the permission is being denied in the C drive, all my folders and files are located in C, I dont even have another drive

Comment: No, you misread the error message. It says nothing about the place where you don't have permissions.

Comment: "in my console its creating a list of the href links, which is what I want" - I thought you wanted to print to a csv file?

Comment: Ok, well where else could it be if I only have a C drive? Can you please provide a more substantive answer than "no, you misread the error message" that doesn't really help me.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions I gave you earlier?

Comment: I want to create a csv file from that output yes, I have seen other threads about exporting nokogiri data to csv and this is how they did and had no problems

Comment: how do i print the value of `Dir.getwd` like I said im super new, sorry for being so stupid lol

Comment: `puts Dir.getwd`

Comment: Okay I get `C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++`

Comment: Well, that's where you can't write files. Double check your permissions there. Might even be some windows sandboxing mechanism.

Comment: Also, don't write to program files. Be explicit, `CSV.open("C:\\\\file.csv", "wb")`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You already gave the answer in the comments, do you want to write an answer

Comment: @TraversWoodward: don't change questions like that. It's now a competely different question. Also pay attention to quotes and backslashes.

Comment: I'm not attempting to change questions lol, I am just trying to get this solved, what does that mean please help me

Comment: @gates added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have literally given myself ownership of the entire C: drive

Contrary to what you assert, you don't have write permissions **everywhere** on drive C:. Something is preventing you from writing in the current working dir (`Dir.getwd`).

Presumably, you have write access to at least root of C:? If so, try writing there.

```
CSV.open("c:/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
```

Comment: That still gives me permission denied, I honestly don't know why its not allowing me to write at all.  I changed the ownership of everyfile on the c drive to myself, I have full admin privileges, it almost seems like there must be a bug. I dont even know at this point

Comment: @TraversWoodward: did you try to do _exactly_ as in my answer? or you made some modifications?

Comment: @TraversWoodward: "I changed the ownership of every file": yes, you'll also need every folder, not only file. Actually, just one folder. The one you'll be writing to.

Comment: @TraversWoodward Just copy the file to the D drive and open terminal(shell) from there, and execute the code

Comment: I got it guys, I messed with permissions on different groups till basically any user on my computer had access to write and it worked, thanks so much for all the help